# my C# winform needs to detect when other applications enter/exit/run-in TRUE fullscreen, prefer by events

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events, internals

my C# winform application needs put itself in standby mode during time other application runs in true fullscreen mode (not only maximized), like video games, video movies, powerpoint.

I need a method to detect if currently there is other application in fullscreen.

Is there a possibility to register to events which will fire when other application enters/exits fullscreen?

for both needs, I'll appreciate to have code snippets.

Comment: How do you define "fullscreen"?

Comment: A "TRUE-full-screen-mode" covers the whole desktop with a black background and the application sits in the middle of the screen. I MUST ignore just "maximize-to-full-screen" mode which is totally different - just maximizing application area to maximum.

and as I'm not so familiar, I'd appreciate some code snippet which I can start from it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437352/how-to-implement-full-screen-mode) "full screen mode" is not that special, just create the right type of window and the OS will treat it as full screen. Once you know that, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202644/is-there-an-api-for-vista-to-detect-if-the-desktop-is-running-full-screen) how to detect such windows.